# Move directory to directory containing whitespaces

Tags: swift, command-line

I'm making a command line script with script, I want to move a directory to another directory. the directory I want to move my directory into is called "Template Files"

I'm trying to move it in the following way

```
let templatePath = "\"~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/\""
let directoryName = "DTT\\ MVP"
do {
    try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: "\(currentPath)\(directoryName)", toPath: "\(templatePath)\(directoryName)")
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

But it gives me the following error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“DTT MVP” couldn’t be moved to
>   “File Templates” because either the former doesn't exist, or the
>   folder containing the latter doesn't exist

does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major issues

1. You must not escape paths in Swift or Objective-C.
2. The tilde is not expanded automatically.

Further it's highly recommended to use the URL related API which provides convenient (and reliable) methods to concatenate the path components.

Assuming `currentURL` is an URL instance I suggest this syntax

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let libraryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let templateURL = libraryURL.appendingPathComponent("Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates")
    let directoryName = "DTT MVP"
    let source = currentURL.appendingPathComponent(directoryName)
    let destination = templateURL.appendingPathComponent(directoryName)
    try fileManager.moveItem(at: source, to: destination)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```